# How to set image as selected for all the <input type="file">

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Let me explain with one example

```
<input type="file" id="image_all" name="image_all">


<input type="file" id="image_1" name="image_1">
<input type="file" id="image_2" name="image_2">

<input type="submit" id="submit_image" name="submit_image" value="SUBMIT">
```

Here, I have mainly 3 file inputs.
Now, what I want is
suppose I select one image by clicking on `<input type="file" id="image_all" name="image_all">` element then i want to set the same image as selected for below input file

```
<input type="file" id="image_1" name="image_1">
<input type="file" id="image_2" name="image_2">
```

Once i click on submit button total 3 image should be processed to server.

Comment: The File object is likely read-only.  But why not do this logic server side as sending the same image 3 times is wasteful.

Comment: Any reason why you want to add three same images on three different inputs ?

Comment: Yes there will be a checkbox for each input file element so only checked input files will be added only but currently, I have given example for all the inputs